# is cpu registers are Independent on each processers, threads?

Tags: cpu, cpu-registers

is cpu registers are "actually" independents on each processers, or threads right?

I mean like they cannot access or share on processers, threads

Comment: Yes. Each logical core has its own registers.

Comment: @Leeor  mean processers(like .exe files)

Comment: First of all lets specify what architecture we are talking about? If it is **x86** in **protected mode** then As @Leeor has said each logical core has it's own register but processes can't share their state because of **context switch**  procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding cpu registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937135/understanding-cpu-registers)

Comment: @BoPersson: if you can edit the tags to include `[assembly]`, I can close this as a duplicate of the Q&A you found, or [How each thread can have CPU registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10371842).  (I came across this while looking for dups for [Are x86-64 CPU registers shared among multiple cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51494024))