# Understanding cpu registers

Tags: linux, assembly, cpu, cpu-registers

I'm very beginner in assembly language and trying to understand how these all work. My question may seem very dumb but anyway, it's not quite clear to me.

Consider the following simple program:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:

    mov eax, [text]
    mov [val], eax
    mov ecx, val
    mov eax, 4
    mov edx, 7
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

segment .bss
    val resb 2

segment .data
    text db "Th"
    len equ $- text
```

Here we update values in registers and print it out with system call. But I'm wondering what if `OS` (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04) schedules some process on the same core. It means the process updates CPU registers in its own way. How does OS linux handle it? I mean each process has its own consistent registers value and not affected by some another process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the kernel is running, it keeps somewhere (in kernel memory) a backup of the register contents of the current task (on many processors, there might be some machine instruction or hardware mechanism to help that).

When the kernel runs the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) and it choose to run some task, that register state is restored. Notice that Linux has [preemptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) scheduling. Read about [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) and [CPU modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes). Try several times `cat /proc/interrupts` in a terminal. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more about `/proc/`. Read more about [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

When that task asks (e.g. via some system call) to run, the kernel starts by backing up the register contents.

Read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable book).

Each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has, from the point of view of [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) code, its register content, its set of file descriptors, its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) etc... (and the kernel, including its scheduler, is managing all that). For multi-threaded processes, every [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) has its register content (but they share 
some state - notably virtual address space, file descriptors, etc... - with other threads in the same process).

Comment: So context-switch requires unloading registers and cache somewhere to memory. It seems quite heavy operation. Can you point out if there a way to prevent OS scheduling some other process on the core I'm executing my app. Or this is OS specific?

Comment: No, there is no way. You need to read that *Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces* book. And yes, it is OS and processor specific. Yes, context switching is a heavy operation but processors run fast enough to make it possible in microseconds and happening hundreds of times per second on a recent laptop or desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Upon switching between processes on the same core, the OS saves the registers of the previous process. That is called context-switching (you may search for more details). Then the OS restores the registers of the next process.

Comment: It means each core have the separated set of registers, right?

Comment: Actually every schedulable task (notably processes and threads) has its register content managed by the kernel

Comment: @St.Antario each logical core has its own set of registers, but I think you meant each thread... yes, the context is saved and restored for each thread by the system, so it looks to the thread as no interruption has happened.

Comment: @St.Antario - Like Serge hints at, each core can often [pretend to be several cores](https://superuser.com/questions/122536/what-is-hyper-threading-and-how-does-it-work) and hold more than one thread loaded. It still looks like a separate register set for each thread but it saves the time to load and store at each context switch.